# GCP Cloud IAP OAuth2: Expected JWT to have 3 parts separated by a '.' but there are 2 parts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, jwt, openid, google-iap

I've secured a Google App Engine Application behind Cloud IAP - the endpoint now requires Google Sign-in via the browser as expected and works fine once I've added the right permissions. However, when I try to use Postman / MS PowerApps OAuth2 authentication I get the following error: Expected JWT to have 3 parts separated by a '.' but there are 2 parts.

Here are my Postman settings:

```
Grant Type: Authorization Code

Callback URL: Authed Callback URL (added to list in console)

Auth URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth

Access Token URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

Client ID: IAP-App-Engine-app ClientID

Client Secret:  IAP-App-Engine-app Client Secret

Scope: openid email

Client Authentication: Send as Basic Auth Header
```

Is there a solution for Cloud IAP OAuth2?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud IAP requires an OAuth Identity Token. You are trying to use an OAuth Access Token.

Comment: Thanks, I've coped the id_token stored by Postman into the Bearer Header and it worked just fine. Do you know if there's an automatic way of doing that?

Comment: I would post a new question on Postman. I have answered your question on OAuth Tokens, but I don't use Postman for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer searching through the documentation for Identity Platform.

https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/identity-howto

> IAP also passes the user's identity to your backend service in the following HTTP headers. These headers should have the namespace prefix accounts.google.com.

If you change the Header Prefix from the default `Bearer` to `accounts.google.com` when requesting a token, the subsequent call to the IAP-secured resource will succeed.